# POST Method not generating a new row

Tags: c#, sql, api, postman

I'm trying to use API methods and playing around. I have had an issue with the POST method.. when posting through Postman it keeps overwrite the id in my database. So, it just doesn't create a new id just keep adding it over id '0'

I have tried modified the primary key columns and adjusted to be "TRUE" in IS identity as well as Identity increment

Here is my post method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage create(Product product)  
{
    try
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        myDBBEntities.Products.Add(product);
        myDBBEntities.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

class:

```
public partial class Product
{        
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, What I need is when posting something to sql I need the a new row to be created with the new data not overwrite the existing one. I'm not sure what is missing. can someone please help me out

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share the details of how you initialise and use the context `myDBBEntities`?

Comment: My DBBEntities is my model for connecting to my table in the database using ADO.NET entity data model. 

so here is the declaration
'public class ProductController : ApiController
    {

        private iAbufar3Entities myDBBEntities = new iAbufar3Entities();'
@MohanRamalingam